# Ask user for list input in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, user-input, io-monad, do-notation

I found this code online, but it's not running.

```
main = do
 xs <- getLine []
print xs
```

So how do I ask the user for list input in Haskell? I am new to Haskell, please explain when you answer. Thanks.

Comment: There should be a new line after `getLine`, and that `[]` shouldn't be there. And make sure you line up the `p` of `print` with the `x` in `xs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it e.g. like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  xs <- getLine
  let { ints :: [Int] 
      ; ints = read xs 
      }
  print $ take 2 ints
```

and you must type in the input in a valid list syntax, e.g.

```
[1,2,3]
```

Do take note, each line in a `do`-block must start at the same indentation level (unless explicit separators `{ ; }` are used).

Answer (score 1):

`getLine` is an `IO` action that produces a string, nothing else. You need to process that string once you receive it. As an example, here's an `IO` action that will parse an appropriate input into a list of `Int` values.

```
getIntList :: IO [Int]
getIntList = fmap read getLine

main = do
         ints <- getIntList
         print ints
```

There is a `Read` instance for lists, so the following works:

```
> read "[1,2,3]" :: [Int]
[1,2,3]
```

`getIntList` uses the `Functor` instance for `IO` to apply `read` to the string that `getLine` will produce; `read`'s concrete type will be inferred from the type given to `getIntList`: since `getIntList :: IO [Int]`, then `fmap read :: IO String -> IO [Int]`, and so `read :: String -> [Int]` will be used.